# React Source code changes not reflecting in browser DOM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, liferay, web-development-server

I am using react with Liferay and this is an issue that I only observe on the linux server that we host our website on, not my local tomcat server.
The problem is that every file changes/ code changes that are made reflect in the source script after building the gradle project. What does not reflect is the new code on the web browser.

Here are some examples to describe this issue better:

1. If I add a `console.log()` to the constructor of the webpage - It does not print the same on the console.
2. If I change a `<p>TITLE</p>` to `<p>TITLE-TITLE</p>` - I see the code changes in the source code but not on the browser webpage.

I was able to conclude that this has something to do with React JS as all my other Java and JSP page changes do get reflected.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
   "dependencies":{
      "bootstrap":"^4.5.0",
      "bootstrap4-dialog":"^4.3.4",
      "popper.js":"^1.14.1",
      "create-react-ref":"^0.1.0",
      "datatables.net":"^1.10.20",
      "hashmap":"^2.4.0",
      "jquery":"^3.4.1",
      "react":"15.6.2",
      "react-dom":"15.6.2",
      "react-router-dom":"^4.0.0"
   },
   "devDependencies":{
      "babel-cli":"^6.26.0",
      "babel-preset-env":"^1.7.0",
      "babel-preset-react":"6.24.1",
      "liferay-npm-bundler":"latest"
   },
   "main":"lib/index.es.js",
   "name":"SearchPageController",
   "scripts":{
      "build":"babel --source-maps -d build/resources/main/META-INF/resources src/main/resources/META-INF/resources && liferay-npm-bundler"
   },
   "version":"1.0.0"
}
```

I am new to Liferay and react and facing this problem. Any help or support would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After checking that it changed the correct page:

1. Stop the server
2. Clear your browser cache
3. `nmp install`
4. `npm run dev`